# pandas - first value bigger than a given value

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume that x is a sorted column containing some data with a "<" relation (e.g. floats, integer, strings). I am given a constant - say 5 - and I want to extract the first value in x bigger than that constant.

Now, I don't want to use a boolean comparison like "x > 5", because this will involve some unnecessary comparisons. So my question: Is there a simple function which I can use that does the trick without implicitly looping over ALL elements?

In essence I want something akin to a for loop with a break statement - once the first value bigger than x was found. (But with C-speed)

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [mre], and read about [ask]. Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: The [numpy.searchsorted](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) function may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
import bisect

def find_first_greater(sorted_column, constant):
    index = bisect.bisect_right(sorted_column, constant)
    if index < len(sorted_column):
        return sorted_column[index]
    else:
        return None  # No value greater than the constant found

# Example usage
x = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
constant = 5
result = find_first_greater(x, constant)
print(result)  # Output: 7
```

In the example above, bisect.bisect_right(sorted_column, constant) returns the index at which the constant should be inserted in the sorted column to maintain its order. By accessing sorted_column[index], you get the first value greater than the constant. If the index is equal to the length of the column, it means there is no value greater than the constant.

The bisect module is implemented in C and provides an efficient way to find the insertion point in a sorted list, making it a suitable choice for your task.

Comment: This is great - thanks. I will use this. But I find it slightly puzzling that there seems to be no pandas-function to perform such a standard task with a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# assuming df is your DataFrame and 'column' is your sorted column
df = pd.DataFrame({'column': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})

# set the constant
constant = 5

# get the first value in 'column' that is greater than the constant
value = df.loc[np.argmax(df['column'] > constant), 'column']

print(value)
```

There's still numpy